# How to encode a non-special character to HTML entity in Java

Tags: java, encoding, html-entities

The following code:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("&#72;&#101;&#108;&#108;&#111;&#32;&#87;&#111;&#114;&#108;&#100;");
```

gives:

```
Hello World
```

But I'd like to know how to get back to the decoded string from "Hello World". I have tried the escapeHtml method, but this only encodes special characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But I'd like to know how to get back to the decoded string from "Hello World". I have tried the escapeHtml method, but this doesn't do anything useful.

Not true about "anything useful"; if your test string contained HTML special characters like <,>,&, the function would've turned it into &lt; &gt; and &amp; (and change other upper ISO8859-1 codes into entities).

If you need to encode it back to Unicode entity format, just iterate through the String codepoints:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    System.out.print("&#" + str.codePointAt(i) + ";");
```

Comment: Thanks MaDa. I have edited my question to reflect the answer but have left the question the same, as I was aware that special characters were encoded.